# Why does starting `tmux` on sway launch over `swaymsg` does make tmux inaccesible?

Tags: linux, tmux, nixos, swaywm

I want to start `tmux` server on sway startup.
Therefore I created in `sway.conf` the following:

```shell
exec ~/.config/sway/scripts/start-up.sh
```

in which script I start tmux as such:

```shell
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# shellcheck disable=SC1091,SC2034
# set -e
# set -u

LOG=~/.sway-startup.log

# Save stdout and stderr to file
exec 3>&1 4>&2 >"$LOG" 2>&1

# Start tmux and make terminal on workspace 1.
echo "Start tmux, let it recreate the workspaces with resurrect"
tmux start-server
echo "Server started."
sleep 3

tmux list-sessions || {
    echo "ERROR: The exit-empty is not set to off, so the server directly exits!" >&2
}

# Create one session if not yet existing, detach from it.
tmux new-session -D -s Main-1

echo "Sessions are:"
tmux list-sessions || {
    echo "ERROR: Sessions should now be available restored from tmux-ressurect???!" >&2
}
echo "-----------"

echo "Finished"
```

In the `tmux.conf` I have `set exit-empty false` such that tmux does not quit if no session on `tmux start-server (weird behavior...).

I am really unsure if I need to block the script `start-up.sh` from exiting or not, because the log `~/.sway-startup.log` from launching the script with `swaymsg exec .../start-up.sh`
reports the following:

```
Start tmux, let it recreate the workspaces with resurrect
Server started.
Astrovim: 1 windows (created Sat Nov 25 21:40:20 2023)
Main-1: 1 windows (created Sat Nov 25 21:40:20 2023)
Main-2: 1 windows (created Sat Nov 25 21:40:20 2023)
NixOS: 1 windows (created Sat Nov 25 21:40:20 2023)
duplicate session: Main-1 ### <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<- thats because resurrect created the above sessions automatically. 
Sessions are:
Astrovim: 1 windows (created Sat Nov 25 21:40:20 2023)
Main-1: 1 windows (created Sat Nov 25 21:40:20 2023)
Main-2: 1 windows (created Sat Nov 25 21:40:20 2023)
NixOS: 1 windows (created Sat Nov 25 21:40:20 2023)
-----------
Finished
```

After that when I `tmux a` **it reports there are `no sessions`**. This is so weird, the server runs as I can see in `btop` (running under my user name) but also using `tmux -S /run/user/1000/tmux-1000 a` pointing to the socket does report `no sessions`?

I am really puzzled and dont know whats going on? How can I resolve this strange issue?
Somehow this is permission problem when starting over `swaymsg`.

Comment: At the end of your script please add `tmux display-message -p '#{socket_path}'`. Restart and check the log. The point is `tmux -S garbage a` may show `no sessions` (and create `garbage`), so let's better be sure what the path of the socket is.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

In NixOS using homemanager, some env variables are not yet sourced when this `start-up.sh` script runs. The one missing is `TMUX_TMPDIR` which is set afterwards.

I needed to write out this variable to be able to source it in the startup script by doing with `home-manager`:

```
  # We need this file to source in `~/.config/sway/scripts/start-up.sh`
  # to be able to properly start tmux because these variables are not
  # yet sourced.
  xdg.configFile."tmux/.tmux-env".text = ''
    TMUX_TMPDIR="${config.home.sessionVariables.TMUX_TMPDIR}"
  '';
```

So when sway started it wrote the `default` socket to `/tmp/$USER-1000/default` etc. which was not the directory which tmux was looking for after the sessionVariables were set.